# Convert european time format to timestamp

Tags: php, date, format, unix-timestamp

What is the most efficient way to convert a given European formatted date (DD/MM/YY) to the correct timestamp?

Example:
10/11/12 should output 1352505600 as the 10th November 2012, and not the October 11th 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $eu_date);
echo $date->format("U");
```

Comment: Shouldn't that format on the first line be `d/m/y` instead of `y/m/d`? I tried editing the answer but StackOverflow said I couldn't because it was less than 6 characters).

Comment: @JordanLev That's a minor detail overlooked for three and a half years that is now fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the 2nd optional variable to the date function to feed it the unix timestamp

Answer (score -2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: yes I tryed that, PHP isn't that european to assume day and month position of a string